# how can I get the values of each line using fileinput.input in python

Tags: python

I have this csv:

mycsv.csv

```
name,last name  
yeison, smith
lola, boa
elmo, spitia
anderson, exneider
juan, ortega
```

I want to show the value of each column. something like:

```
print (line["word"])
print (line[0])


import fileinput

with fileinput.input('mycsv.csv', inplace=True) as f:
 for line in f:
    #if f.lineno() == 2:
    if line["name"] == "yeison":
        print('german, ezequiel')
    else:
        print(line, end='')
```

Comment: you should either use [csv](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html) or [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) module, not `fileinput`.

Comment: @Nenri I did it because I can not find a better way to replace a line of my csv. If I could find and could use a better way to replace a "n" line of a CSV, I would do it without a doubt.

Comment: Look at Ayoub's answer, i will comment on it how to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this simple code to read your cvs file (pandas)

```
# Load the Pandas libraries with alias 'pd' 
import pandas as pd 
# Read data from file 'filename.csv' 
# (in the same directory that your python process is based)
# Control delimiters, rows, column names with read_csv (see later) 
data = pd.read_csv("filename.csv") 
# Preview the first 5 lines of the loaded data 
data.head()
```

Comment: and to replace a "n" line u can do `data['column'][n] = newValue` for whatever column you want (this is to answer a question asked in the comments of the OP)

Comment: This code looks easier. what is "column"? do you recommend using it this way?

Comment: @unusuario for example, in ur csv, if you want to modify "anderson" into "christopher" do `data['name'][4] = "christopher"`

Comment: for example data = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', names=['col0', 'col1',])
print(data)

Comment: @AyoubBenayache with this code, can I read a csv while writing at the same time? One last question, how can I list my records?

Comment: yes you can read and write , but you need to add a thread  if you want read your file continuously. check this link form more details, it shows you different strategies to do that https://realpython.com/python-csv/

Answer (score 0):

If your data isn't large you can just open and parse your file line by line as such:

```
with open("mycsv.csv") as f:
    lines = [line.strip('\n') for line in f]

for ln in lines:
    abc = ln.split(',')
    if(len(abc) > 1):
        print(abc[0],abc[1])
```

Otherwise you could use the `csv` module to do this effectively

Comment: I did it because I can not find a better way to replace a line of my csv. If I could find and could use a better way to replace a "n" line of a CSV, I would do it without a doubt.

Comment: If you are replacing a line in your CSV then you should use one of the modules suggested in other answers, the best my approach could do is load the CSV and create an entirely new one from that data, which would be much slower than what `pandas` or `csv` can do.